# If sequence of functions converges, then first crossing time of each function also converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n : [0,\infty] \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be sequence of functions such that $f_n(t)$ converges to linear function $ht$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for some $h>0$ for all $t\in[0,\infty]$. Define, for $p>0$ fixed, $\tau_n = \inf\{t\geq0:f_n(t)>p\}.$ Show that $\tau_n$ converges to $\frac{p}{h}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no thoughts or ideas to approach.

Comment: Assume further that $f_n$ is non-decreasing function.